# Notification not being triggered after promise

Tags: node.js, push-notification, promise, onesignal

```
function _createMemory(memory) {
  const populate = ['update', 'cause', 'creator'];
  const where = {id: memoryIds};
  const causeId = req.param('causeId');
  const adminIDs = _.map(Cause.admins, 'id');
  const message = {
    app_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    contents: {"en": "English"},
    filters: [{"field": "tag", "key": "userId", "relation": "=", "value": 'adminIDs'}]
  }

  return Memory.create(memory)
    .then(memory => {
      return memory.update && !memory.cause
        ? getCauseFromUpdate(memory.update)
            .then(causeId => Memory.update({id: memory.id}, {cause: causeId}))
            .then(memories => memories[0])
        : Promise.resolve(memory)
    }).then(PushNotificationService.sendNotification(message))
}
```

The issue I'm having right now is that for some reason its not triggering the notification after the "memory is created" the memory and cause should be updated and then a notification should be sent to the cause admins. However right now it's not sending the notification, and I'm not sure why. Would love anyones help!

Comment: How is the _createMemory function being called? Is there anything  that would prevent that function to not be called?

Comment: Good question, it is being called, and the _createMemory function is executing correctly, and the memory is being created correctly. Just nothing as far as notifications being pushed.

Comment: Also, have notifications set up in other parts of the app, and they are working properly.

Comment: I thinking there might be some hints there, if the function is being called, and this the only notification not being sent. What about settings for the Push Notification Service, does something differ there with the other notifications?

Comment: The promises look okay to me, so am thinking, it's just that specific notification.

Comment: Yeah its just strange so in the PushNotificationService, I only export one function which is sendNotification, the only thing that changes really is the filter of who the messages get sent to, so I'm not sure why in this case its not working vs. other cases.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `then(() => PushNotificationService.sendNotification(message))`?

Comment: Either one is fine in this case. I like the way it is currently, just a few less characters. I tried it your way as well, same result.